# mysqli_query(): Empty query in line

Tags: php, ios, mysql, xcode, mysqli

I'm confused by xcode and php due to the fact that the exact same code, which works within the iOS simulator, doesn't work for the iPhone itself.

The php file looks like the following:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","BLACKEDOUT","BLACKEDOUT","BLACKEDOUT"     );

$array = json_decode($_POST["identifier"]);

for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
$name = $array[$i][1];
for($j=0; $j < count($array[$i][0]); $j++)
{
    $nummer = $array[$i][0][$j];

    $query = "SELECT x FROM Z WHERE uniqueID = $nummer";
    $dbConn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=BLACKEDOUT', "BLACKOUT", "BLACKEDOUT");
    $smt = $dbConn->prepare($query);
    $smt->bindParam(1, $phone_num );
    $smt->execute();
    if($smt->rowCount())
        {
             $ergebnisArray[] = [$name,$nummer];
    }
    else 
    {
    }
     }

}
echo json_encode($ergebnisArray);

mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("Could not connect to server");

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

When running the code in the iOS simulator it's all fine, but when I run it on my device it says: as the response string in Xcode: "mysqli_query(): Empty query in on line 30". When I work around that error, I don't get the result I expect either.

Every help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Mixing mysqli and PDO in your code!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that you use BLACKOUT and BLACKEDOUT mixed, and you never use $con. Also, be aware that you define $query inside a loop, so when it iterates zero times, $query never gets defined, thus cannot by used in mysqli_query.

Try this and come back with the result:

```
<?php
$array = json_decode($_POST["identifier"]);

for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
$name = $array[$i][1];
    for($j=0; $j < count($array[$i][0]); $j++)
    {
        $nummer = $array[$i][0][$j];

        $query = "SELECT x FROM Z WHERE uniqueID = '".$nummer."'";
        $dbConn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=BLACKEDOUT', "BLACKOUT", "BLACKEDOUT");
        $smt = $dbConn->prepare($query);
        $smt->bindParam(1, $phone_num );
        $smt->execute();
        if($smt->rowCount())
            {
                 $ergebnisArray[] = [$name,$nummer];
        }
        else 
        {
        }
    }

}
echo json_encode($ergebnisArray);
?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the improved code! 
After I implemented it I tested it on iPhone simulator -> works.
But as in my first try it doesn't work for the iPhone itself.
So can the problem lie within the size of the array that is sent to the php script? Seems to be the only difference between simulator and device.

Comment: @seb To improve it a little better, you should put the `$dbConn` outside the `for`-loops, as you don't need to create a new PDO-object every iteration of `$j`. Also, are you sure that it's `localhost` on your iPhone too (meaning that the SQL-server is localhost for the iPhone)? If you suspect it might be the array, just echo it out both places and look for differences. Might also want to echo out `$query` to make sure that it has the proper values.

Comment: @Qirel thank you, makes sense. I changed it as you suggested.  :) 
The array, it seems like it, is not "filled" while running the app over the iPhone. That would explain the mysql_query(): Empty query error in the first place. That again would point into the direction that localhost is not correct, wouldn't it?

Comment: Just wondering: I accessed the .php file which is already up on the website. So localhost must be correct for both, the simulator and the iPhone, right?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the unused and empty $query as I suggested above?

Comment: Put the connection in a `try/catch`-block (something like `try {
    $dbConn = new PDO(.....);
    // Do query and stuff
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}`) to make sure it actually connects. If it does, and it still doesn't fetch any results, you should check that your `$query` is correct by `echo $query;` (as I mentioned above). You should always check for errors/exceptions, as this `try/catch`-block will do.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for all your effort guys! 
I did exactly as you wrote your code @vacsora and removed the query as you suggested. The code works perfectly in the iOS simulator but not on the iPhone itself. 
@Qirel! Thank you for your effort, too. Php is new to me so I'm struggling with try/catch and debugging.
I just don't know where the mistake is supposed to be. Just the code in iOS Simulator works perfectly...

Comment: Ok, we feel you try hard, don't give up just yet. One way to debug php is to `echo $variable;` to see values during execution. You will delete or put into comment these debug echos later. Cant't figure out what's the difference in simulator and device though because this is server side!

Comment: @vacsora thanks for your encouraging words :). I figured out what the mistake was. it was in the Xcode file, i forgot the following line: 
    [post setString:[post stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
it took me only one day to figure it out :/ oh well, at least its working now on both: simulator and iPhone! Thanks again to you both!